# Allocating array components of derived types

Tags: fortran

I have a type of something like the following

```
 type BOPinfo

     double precision, allocatable :: realQ4(:,:), realQ6(:,:)

  end type BOPinfo
```

I have been able to ascertain how to initialize elements in a derived type when the elements are real or integer scalars.

However, I can't figure out how to tell a variable of type `BOPinfo` what the size of the arrays `realQ4` and `realQ6` are, and maybe how to initialize them to zero. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please don't use just the tag `fortran90` when actually using Fortran 2003. There are no allocatable structure components in Fortran 90.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allocatable (or pointer) type components cannot have default initialization.  This applies to both deferred shape arrays and allocatable/pointer scalars.  Allocatable components always have an initial status of "not allocated".  Instead, one allocates and zeros the individual components separately from the object's declaration:

```
type(BOPinfo) test
integer n1, n2, m1, m2

allocate (test%realQ4(n1,m1), test%realQ6(n2,m2))
test%realQ4 = 0
test%realQ6 = 0
```

This is different from default (or explicit) initialization, and one may also set the value in a structure constructor (as in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22280912/3157076)).

Under Fortran 2003 there are other approaches for the dynamic size, including parameterized derived types (which are now widely supported in recent compiler versions).

Answer (score 2):

It is also possible to use a [structure constructor](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/stdxe/2013/composerxe/compiler/fortran-mac/GUID-6521CC96-2A0E-4CE0-8036-3238F7476C34.htm) to create a derived-type-valued expression. The constructor is a function with the same name as the type.

```
variable = BOPinfo(array1, array2)
```

where `array1` and `array2` are arrays with the appropriate rank. You can also pass `null()` if you want the component to be `not allocated`.

In Fortran 2008 you can even omit the allocatable components and they will have the status of `not allocated`.